# uniform_real_distribution Is Not Uniform

Tags: c++, random

Please, help me understand this. After running the snippet:

```
random_device randomEngine;
mt19937 generatorEngine(randomEngine());
uniform_real_distribution<double> unifRandomValue(
                                       numeric_limits<double>::min(), 
                                       numeric_limits<double>::max());

double test[1000];
for (int i{ 0 }; i < 1000; ++i) {
    test[i] = unifRandomValue(generatorEngine);
}
```

Why is every generated value in the range `[1.0E306, 1.8E308]`? I was expecting a random value uniformly distributed from near 0 to the max of double type.

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Here is a more complete example :

```
const size_t size{ 1000 };
std::random_device randomEngine;
std::mt19937 generatorEngine(randomEngine());
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unifRandomValue(
                                std::numeric_limits<double>::min(), 
                                std::numeric_limits<double>::max());

std::array<double, size> test;
for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i) {
    test[i] = unifRandomValue(generatorEngine);
}

auto minMaxIt = std::minmax_element(test.begin(), test.end());

// average without overflow
double average{ 0.0 };
for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i) {
    average += test[i] / size;
}

std::cout << "min value : " << *minMaxIt.first << std::endl;
std::cout << "max value : " << *minMaxIt.second << std::endl;
std::cout << "average   : " << average << endl;

// one possible output (they are all similar)
//  min value : 1.73361e+305
//  max value : 1.79661e+308
//  average : 8.78467e+307
```

Comment: How do you know they are in that range? Did you maybe look at the values of `test` in the debugger before assigning values? Please make a [mcve] where you print the values.

Comment: Did you try calculating the average, standard deviation etc?

Comment: Certainly can be counter-intuitive. It was for me.

Comment: Looks uniform to me.

Comment: To be precise, there is no such thing as a uniform real distribution. So what's the actual maximum number your generator can generate?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Well, that's the property of a *uniform generator*:

**90% of values will be in the highest order of magnitude you specify.**

Think smaller; consider the integer range 0 to 99 inclusive: 90% of the drawings will have 2 digits.

Comment: That example is very good for intuition, which often fails one when dealing with this subject. Reminds me of the old counting riddle: Frogs spawn every day, and double their number every time they spawn. It is given that it took them 10 days to fill their pond to the brim. How long did it take them to fill it half-way? Same basic idea :)

Comment: Thanks to all. Bathsheba, your answer is simple and really intuitive. I did not really think about it and conclude immediately of an error from my part. This is obvious now! Thanks again.

Comment: @StoryTeller Gotta say, I thought that was the easiest riddle in the world before I realized I was being stupid.

Comment: @StoryTeller, the riddle [still works as an exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429872/a-lily-pad-doubles-in-area-every-second-after-one-minute-it-fills-the-pond-ho).

Comment: Answers with helpful analogies are always the best, IMHO.

Comment: @CarstenS - I wonder what's in those waters to make things multiply so fast ;)